# Why can closed questions still be answered?

Tags: discussion, answers, closed-questions

According to Stack Overflow's help page, closed questions cannot be answered:

> Questions that need additional work or that are not a good fit for
>   this site may be closed by experienced community members. **Closed
>   questions cannot be answered**
>
> - [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)

However, every once in a while, I see a closed question with an answer given *after* is was closed:

[image: Closed 15 minutes ago]

... and on the same question, an answer is given, seven minutes after it was closed:

[image: Answer given]

When a question is closed, it blocks users from writing answers by removing the answer text area. If a user is in the middle of typing an answer, the *Post Your Answer* becomes disabled, preventing further answers to be given:

[image: Question closed during writing an answer]

So how are some users answering closed questions? Why can closed questions still be answered?

Comment: there is a grace period for answers started prior to the question being closed.

Comment: And how many is that grace period? I find it so annoying, writing an answer, and just when I'm about to finish, the question is being closed and I've done all that writing for nothing.